# When are sparse arrays effective?

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

Sparse arrays are not effective in *Mathematica* 10. More computational time is needed to perform arithmetic operations on sparse arrays. Their size is also bigger than normal arrays. Here is a simple demonstration:

```
MatNormal = HankelMatrix[2000];
MatSparse = SparseArray[MatNormal];
multNormal = Timing[MatNormal.MatNormal];
multSparse = Timing[MatSparse.MatSparse];
Grid[{{"", "Normal", "Sparse", "Ratio"}, {"Computation Time", 
multNormal[[1]], multSparse[[1]], 
multSparse[[1]]/multNormal[[1]]}, {"Bytes Used", 
ByteCount[multNormal[[2]]], ByteCount[multSparse[[2]]], 
1.*ByteCount[multSparse[[2]]]/ByteCount[multNormal[[2]]]}},
```

\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{} & \text{Normal} & \text{Sparse} & \text{Ratio} \\
 \text{Computation Time} & 0.639604 & 8.923257 & 13.9512 \\
 \text{Bytes Used} & 32000152 & 64017136 & 2.00053 \\
\end{array}

Am I missing something? What's the point of using sparse arrays?

Comment: A Hankel Matrix is not particularly sparse, for one thing, you pay for updating zeroes in a sparse array, and the result of `HankelMatrix` is packed, so quite efficient (i.e, unpacked it's MUCH bigger). Learn where it is appropriate to use each kind...

Comment: "what's the point of using sparse arrays then?" - it's supposed to be used for matrices with a lot of "background elements" ($0$ usually), and you have chosen a particularly good example of something that does **not** fit the bill. You get what you pay for, bub.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I didnt know you were from Arkansas too, bub!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have shown that when the arrays are not sparse, using SparseArray is futile. Let's look at a case when it is sparse:

```
MatSparse = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2000, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 2000} -> 4}];
MatNormal = Normal[MatSparse];
multNormal = Timing[MatNormal.MatNormal];
multSparse = Timing[MatSparse.MatSparse];
Grid[{{"", "Normal", "Sparse", "Ratio"}, {"Computation Time", 
   multNormal[[1]], multSparse[[1]], 
   multSparse[[1]]/multNormal[[1]]}, {"Bytes Used", 
   ByteCount[multNormal[[2]]], ByteCount[multSparse[[2]]], 
   1.*ByteCount[multSparse[[2]]]/ByteCount[multNormal[[2]]]}}]
```

[image]

Quite a difference!

Comment: I +1 this, of course.... OP should also keep in mind that sparsity of eventual result comes into play, that is, in the OP and your `Dot` examples, the result does not become very sparse until the arguments themselves are already *very* sparse - so if one knows that even though the intermediate parts are reasonably sparse, if along the way you end up *not* sparse, might be worth just going with packed/unpacked non-sparse pieces....